# How to maintain two custom cells in one table view with segmented control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-cell

In my application i want to display two custom cells in one tableview with segment selection.when the user click on the segment=0 display the 1st custom cell and segment =1 display 2nd custom cell.
Here is my code.

```
-(void)callSegmentSelected
{
value = (int)segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
        NSString *UDID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"kPrefKeyForUserID"];
        NSString *catId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"kPrefKeyForCatID"];
        NSString *sessionKey = @"akjsda9s8dadandlakd9";
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"API"];
        NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:GETCONTEST,catId,UDID,sessionKey];
        NSData *myJSONData =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:myJSONData]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(str.length > 0)
        {
            NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *error;
            NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]);
            fldExamTitleArray =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[[fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"examid"] intValue]] forKey:@"kPrefKeyForExamID"];
            NSLog(@"Examid: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"kPrefKeyForExamID"]);
            [defaults synchronize];
            [progressHud hide:YES];
            [self.myContestTableView reloadData];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
}
else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{
}
else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
{
}
```

and here is cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value == 0)
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    ContestTableViewCell * cell = (ContestTableViewCell *)[myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *myNib;
        myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [myNib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.fldExamTitleLbl.text = [[fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
}
else
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
        ContestRewardCell *cell = (ContestRewardCell *)[myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *myNib;
            myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestRewardCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.examTitleLbl.text = [[fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
}
return nil;
}
```

i am getting this error,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 468}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource ()'

Here i am not implenting this method that's way data not showing in my tableview.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value1 == 0)
{
    return 102;
}
else if(value1 == 1)
{
    return 193;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is return cell? you are always returning nil ! The question shows lack of debugging from OP's end.

Comment: BTW - you haven't accepted a single answer to any of your past questions. You really should go back and accept any answer that solved your questions.

Comment: @rmaddy that answers not working for me.

Comment: Are you saying that of all the questions you've every asked on this site, no one has every posted an answer that solved any of your issues?

Comment: i am saying not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have returned `nil` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Use like following :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value == 0)
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell";
    ContestTableViewCell * cell = (ContestTableViewCell *)[myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *myNib;
        myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [myNib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.fldExamTitleLbl.text = [[fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
    return cell;
}
else
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
        ContestRewardCell *cell = (ContestRewardCell *)[myContestTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *myNib;
            myNib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ContestRewardCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell =[myNib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.examTitleLbl.text = [[fldExamTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fldexamtitle"];
        return cell;

}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: @MangiReddy Did you not notice the two `return cell;` statements added where they need to be?

Comment: i changed accroding to your code it displaying empty cells.@nirav gadhiya

Comment: @rmaddy "it looks like my code.what changes in this code"- The OP  not even care to appreciate the effort made and neither have the patience to see the code carefully.

Comment: SF users can point out where can be the possible error happened or can detect the logical flaw , but don't expect them to spoon-feed the whole code for you, for that you have use your brain and basics.

Comment: @Vizllx i am new to iOS.

Comment: @MangiReddy , It seems you are also new to SO. :p